# iOS http POST using Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

I need some help using Alamofire to do a POST to a web page using a username/password throug an API from Twilio.

I have used SwiftRequest from GitHub before, but that doesn't support Swift 2.0.

The code I used (using SwiftRequest) was:

```
        var data = [
            "To" : mobileInput.text as String!,
            "From" : twilioSMSFrom,
            "Body" : String(code) as String
        ]

        var swiftRequest = SwiftRequest()

        swiftRequest.post("https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/\(twilioUsername)/Messages",
            auth: ["username" : twilioUsername, "password" : twilioPassword],
            data: data,
            callback: {err, response, body in
                if err == nil {
                    println("Success: \(response)")
                } else {
                    println("Error: \(err)")
                }
            })
```

How can I translate this to use Alamofire instead?

I have tried searching for a solution, but could find any.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

The solution using Alamofire:

```
        let data = [
            "To" : mobileInput.text as String!,
            "From" : twilioSMSFrom,
            "Body" : String(code) as String
        ]

        Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://\(twilioUsername):\(twilioPassword)@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/\(twilioUsername)/Messages", parameters: data)
            .responseJSON { response in
                print(response.request)
                print(response.response)
                print(response.result)
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/\(twilioUsername)/Messages", parameters: ["username": twilioUsername, "password" : twilioPassword])
     .responseJSON { response in
         print(response.request)
         print(response.response)
         print(response.result)

         if let JSON = response.result.value {
             print("Did receive JSON data: \(JSON)")
         }
         else {
             print("JSON data is nil.")
         }

      }
```

You should definitely check their github page - https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Comment: That returned SUCCESS, but your answer didn't include the data part. How do I make sure that data is sent as well?

Comment: I'm sorry not beeing precise enough. I meant that the data part has to be sent in the POST to be able to get the nessesary data in the result. I've tested your code and it responded with JSON data is nil, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is latest answer of SWIFT 2.2 VERSION
try this one its helps you....

PARAMETERS:-

```
    let params : Dictionary = ["YourKEY" : "YourVALUE"]
```

Post Request_Form:-

```
Alamofire.request(.POST,"Post Your Url HERE", parameters: params, encoding:.JSON).responseJSON
        {
          response in switch response.result 
            {
                  case .Success(let JSON):
         //   print("Success with JSON: \(JSON)")
            //converting json into NSDictionary

            let response = JSON as! NSDictionary
            print(response)

            var array = NSMutableArray!()
            //converting respose form into NSMutableArray formate
            array = response.valueForKey("countryList")as? NSMutableArray

            //example if there is an id
          //  let userId = response.objectForKey("id")!

        case .Failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            }
    }
```